# How to remove bluriness of fonts and 'lock in' effect when combining transform: scale with transition: transform?

Tags: css, css-transitions, css-transforms

When combining transform:scale with transition:scale, the animation has two problems, and the problems are similar in Firefox and Chrome.

1) The font/border is extremely blurry during the transition
2) About 0.3s after the transition, the browser 'locks-in' the new scale. It is hard to explain but you will clearly see from the example.

```
<html>
<body>
  <div id="block">
    <div class="text">123123</div> 
    <div class="text">123123</div> 
    <div class="text">123123</div> 
  </div>
</body>
</html>

<style>
#block {
   margin-top: 100px;
   margin-left: 100px;
   width: 80%;
   height: 300px;
   display: flex;
   flex-direction: column;
}
.text {
   margin: auto;
   width: 250px;    
   font-size: 25px;
   transition: transform 0.5s;
   border: 1px solid blue;
   cursor: pointer;
}
.text:hover {
    transform: scale(1.5);
}
</style>
```

I've tried adding backface-visibility: hidden but this has no effect in Firefox and makes the end of the transition permanently blurred.

Also tried using transform-origin: 100% 0, but no avail.

Take a look at the Codepen:

https://codepen.io/vibonaaci/pen/LKqrPX

Any ideas? If you use the effect on some more stylized elements, the issue really hurts the eyes.

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/50913783/8620333

Comment: That thread does provide some things to tweak around with that improve the situation but still not a 100% clean solution yet. Thank you